# struct member not globally accessible,why so?

Tags: c

```
typedef struct {
int head;
int tail;
}cb;

int norm(){
cb  *ptr=malloc(sizeof(size));
printf("%d",ptr->head);

} 

void main(){
cb *ptr=malloc(sizeof(int));
ptr->head=5;
norm();
}
```

in above code I stored value 5 in head , however when I call function norm, and I print value of head ,it is not displaying 5,how can i resolve this?I want the same value in another function too

Comment: thr function norm has nothing to do with the value you put .. it creates a new structure

Comment: you should pass ptr as a parametre to norm

Comment: What I understood from your reply is, I should pass *ptr as third argument by means of which I will be accessing the same header that I initialised in main function ,right?

Comment: yes right, as now you have two different `cb`. The one in the main and the one inside the funtion

Comment: Hey, thankyou. Its working now.

Comment: also, in `main`, you should `malloc(sizeof(struct cb))`

Answer (score 0):

Couple things: When you allocate the memory, it should be `sizeof(cb)`, not `int`. If you try to access `ptr->tail`, you will get a crash. Next, you should pass a pointer to the structure to `norm(cb *ptr)`, and do not allocate memory inside `norm`, just use the passed pointer.

```
typedef struct {
    int head;
    int tail;
}cb;

int norm(cb *ptr){
    printf("%d",ptr->head);
} 

void main(){
    cb *ptr=malloc(sizeof(cb));
    ptr->head=5;
    norm(ptr);
}
```

Comment: typedef struct {
        int head;
        int tail;
        int *address;
    }cb;

    int norm(cb *ptr){
        printf("%d",ptr->head);
        ptr->address=5;
        /*how can I increment the address */
    } suppose i have added address pointer in struct, how can i access and increment it

Comment: what is `address` the address of? Why is it a pointer? In any case, `ptr->address = 5;` will get you a compiler warning that "int* differs in levels of indirection from int". if you want to access the memory pointed to by `address`, you can do this: `*(ptr->address) = 5;`. Does that answer your question?

Comment: yup,thankyou bro. I was looking to access the value pointed by address. Seems like I can use *(ptr->address) to get that value. Thanks for your input.

Comment: You're welcome. Also, to increment, `*(ptr->address)++` will work.